# Julia: get struct parameters

Tags: julia

Say I have a struct defined as `::GridStruct{::Integer, ::Integer, ::Number}`, for example:

```
Grid = GridStruct(DomainSize, Cells, <irrelevant details>...)
println(typeof(Grid))
```

yields

```
GridStruct{3, Int64, Float64}
```

how can I "extract" (read/get) the inner types/values of (3, Int64, Float64) ?
I would want to be able to read this data for various uses, such as pre-determinind the dimensions (3 in this case) and the types for dispatch (Int64 and Float65 combination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some sneaky generic programming:

```
julia> struct A{T, U, V} end

julia> typeparams(::Type{A{T, U, V}}) where {T,U,V} = (T, U, V)
typeparams (generic function with 1 method)

julia> typeparams(A{3, Int64, Float64})
(3, Int64, Float64)
```

If you want to make this fully generic over the number of generic parameters, you can stick the type parameters in a tuple:

```
julia> struct A{T<:Tuple} end

julia> typeparams(::Type{A{T}}) where {T} = (T.parameters...,)
typeparams (generic function with 1 method)

julia> typeparams(A{Tuple{3, Int64, Float64}})
(3, Int64, Float64)
```

Unfortunately I don't think you can simultaneously make `typeparams` generic over both the main type and its generic parameters (with something like `typeparams(::Type{S{T}}) where {S,T} = (T...,)`); Julia doesn't support it because it would make type inference undecidable in the case of nested generics.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this to be any number of parameters rather than the 3 in this example? And of course not to be limited to stuct named A...

Comment: @TheWhitestOfFangs I think that is difficult. A ugly and risky way is to directly access the `.parameters` field of your type. I do not recommend it, though, and it is considered bad practice. Instead of this entire approach I suggest making more specific functions. For example, you should extend `Base.ndims` for your grid type to return the number of dimensions.

Comment: Could you say a little more on why using `.parameters` would be considered bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

So this is the solution I figured out up to now.
It works, but I don't know if it is the "proper" way to do it... suggestions are welcomed:

```
@inline GetDim(::GridStruct{N}) where {N} = N
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You could also capture all the parameters in a tuple with the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Julia `DataType`s have a `parameters` property that gives you a vector of the type's parameters:

```
julia> struct GridStruct{T1, T2, T3} end

julia> g = GridStruct{3, 2, 1}()
GridStruct{3, 2, 1}()

julia> typeof(g).parameters
svec(3, 2, 1)
```